# Php drop down menu. If value exists in mysql, it is the selected value in drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, foreach

Here is code without mysql

```
foreach ( $transaction_type as $i1=>$opt1 ) : 
echo '<option value="' .htmlspecialchars($opt1) .'"' .( 
(
htmlspecialchars($opt1) == htmlspecialchars($_POST['transaction_type'][$i])
)
? 'selected' : "" ) .'>'.htmlspecialchars($opt1) .'</option>';
endforeach;
```

Trying to modify. If in mysql certain field exists value, the value from mysql is the selected value. Else, echo the same as in code above.

**Update**

Here is code that at least for me is much more understandable. All works.

```
foreach ( $transaction_type as $i1=>$opt1 ) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($opt1);?>"
<?php 
if (
($opt1 == $_POST['transaction_type'][$i]) OR ($opt1 == $result[VatReturnTransactionType01])
}
{
echo 'selected';
}
?> >

<?php echo htmlspecialchars($opt1); ?>

</option>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to read.. there might be an extra bracket or a bracket missing but ...

```
foreach ( $transaction_type as $i => $opt1 ) : 
    $option = '<option value="' .htmlspecialchars($opt1) .'"';

   if(($result[VatReturnTransactionType01] != '' AND 
       htmlspecialchars($opt1) == htmlspecialchars($result[VatReturnTransactionType01]))
       OR htmlspecialchars($opt1) == htmlspecialchars($_POST['transaction_type'][$i]))
   {
       $option .= 'selected';
   }

   $option .= '>'.htmlspecialchars($opt1) .'</option>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Get blank page. Yes, difficult. Possibly will try to make something simpler.

Comment: I missed a bracket at the end of the second line of the if statement ;)

Comment: Unfortunately can not get it to work. Checked brackets. The first after `if`  matches the last after `[$i]))` Second after `if` matches `VatReturnTransactionType01])`. Removed last brackets from `[VatReturnTransactionType01]))` and `[$i]))`

Comment: Ok, so the syntax is correct but is the logic correct? Double check that.

Comment: Tried, but can not get to work... for my brains not understandable:)

Comment: `$i` is not defined, you name the variable `$i1`, I updated the code. Or is `$i` defined somewhere else?

Comment: `[$i]` is defined above in other foreach... Oh, will try some other way. Seems not very reasonably to try with this code.